# Schedule a Task to delete another task

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, taskscheduler, windows-server-2019

I have a scheduled task in EC2 windows server 2019 that runs on start and I would like to delete after it finishes.
I tried to schedule a task to delete it but the task kept running without deleting the other one, but the scripts work from Powershell directly.

```
SCHTASKS /Delete /TN AfterRestartSetup /F
```

I tried to add /z to delete the task right after it is done but it did not work.

```
schtasks /create /tn "AfterRestartSetup" /sc onstart /z /rl highest /ru system /tr "powershell.exe -file C:\scripts\setup\AfterRestartSetup.ps1"
```

I also tried to unregister but it didn't work also:

```
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "AfterRestartSetup"  -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a task like this:

```
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\your-user\" -TaskName "your-task-name"
```

Add the above line to a text file and save it with `ps1` extension. Then create a task on Task Scheduler. In the General tab (of properties window), make sure you check `Run with highest privileges`. The Action should be `Start a program` where the Program/script is `Powershell.exe` and the argument has a complete path to the `ps1` file you created earlier (e.g. C:\Scripts\myTask.ps1).

Comment: Yeah, the same happens it works from PS directly but it doesn't work if I schedule it.